# How to join on like % class.column %

Tags: postgresql, python-3.x, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I need to do the following postgres like

```
join results on task_items.task_item LIKE '%'|| results.result_name||'%'
```

but in flask-sqlalchemy

best I have come up with is

```
join(Results, TaskItems.task_item.like("%{}%".format(Results.result_name)))
```

but this is wrong and outputs SQL:

```
join on task_items.task_item LIKE '%Results.result_name%'
```

Am sure it must be simple, but my searches keep coming up blank

Comment: Untested but I think it's: `TaskItems.task_item.like('%' + Results.result_name + '%')`

Comment: You sir are a gent :-). Put that as an answer and I'll mark it correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should do:

```
TaskItems.task_item.like('%' + Results.result_name + '% ')
```